# C#, How to dynamically create with Reflection.Emit property getter setter in mvvmlight style

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

#### How to create Property like the following in Reflection.Emit

```cs
    private string _Name;

    public override string Name{ get => _Name; set => Set(ref _Name, value); }
```

#### I tried this with Reflection.Emmit

```cs
    private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
      // propertyName = "Name";
      // propertyType = typeof(string);
      // private string _Name;
      FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

      // public string Name {get; set;}
      PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
      // get;
      MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
      ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
      // get => _Name
      getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
      getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
      getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

      // set;
      MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
          tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
            MethodAttributes.Public |
            MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
            MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
            null, new[] { propertyType });

      ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();


      var MvvmLightSetMethod = typeof(ObservableObject)
                               .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                               .Where(m => m.Name == "Set").ToList()[2];

      // set => Set(ref _Name, value);
      setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Mkrefany, fieldBuilder);
      setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
      setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
      setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, propertyName);
      setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, MvvmLightSetMethod);
      setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

      // public string Name {get; set;}
      propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
      propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
    }
```

#### My Problem

If I run this code and call the setter i get  "Invalid class token exception" in set_Name(string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IL to call `Set<T>` is completely wrong.

[`Set<T>`](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/4cbf77ca6fbe91f83cece8fbf288b166c54202c5/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/ObservableObject.cs#L416) has the following signature:

```
protected bool Set<T>(
    ref T field,
    T newValue,
    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
```

Remember that the order of methods returned by `Type.GetMethods` is undefined and can change. **Do not** simply index into this - make sure you get the correct method by specifying its signature. It's also a generic method, so you'll need to call `MakeGenericMethod`.

I've also no idea what you're trying to do with `Mkrefany`. It looks like you were trying to do `ref this.field`, but that's done with `Ldflda`.

Finally, `Set<T>` returns a value, which you'll need to pop before you can return.

Put all of that together, and you get this:

```
var setMethod = (from method in typeof(ObservableObject).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                 where method.Name == "Set"
                 let parameters = method.GetParameters()
                 where parameters.Length == 3 &&
                 parameters[0].ParameterType.IsByRef &&
                 parameters[0].ParameterType.ContainsGenericParameters &&
                 parameters[1].ParameterType.ContainsGenericParameters &&
                 parameters[2].ParameterType == typeof(string)
                 select method).Single().MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);

// set => Set(ref _Name, value);
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Load 'this' -- we'll use it when calling Set later
// Stack: [this]
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Load 'this' again, for accessing 'this.field'
// Stack: [this, this]
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda, fieldBuilder); // Load the address of 'this.field'
// Stack: [this, ref this.field]
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // Load 'value'
// Stack: [this, ref this.field, value]
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, propertyName); // Load 'propertyName'
// Stack: [this, ref this.field, value, propertyName]
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, setMethod);
// Stack: [bool]
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Pop); // Pop the returned value
// Stack: []
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgBgAJDSA6AJQFcA7DbAWxiYDCEHgAc8MKAGUJAN2xgYAZwDcVQgGYGxOgLoBvKnSN0RUCBhhgLAEzrAIEXHWkYAPABUAfAApDx/7AAZnTudIHYMLjWaH7+RqEcMADuAGoAhrhsMDGUccYA2gIZuBIAsjA8wBIAcml8ALoMpPSmECISGACetXx0ALx0HGy4uACU/Z5hGYowqrnGsSZQ2DJpFnTYXGERUXP+ixoMKHSl3uMG83ku3kHbkdF0pKN7xgC+VK9AA=) is an invaluable aid for writing IL.